# Is this difference always positive if the measures are different!

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function that achieves its maximum exactly at points of a set A. We know that Support($\mu$) is contained in the Support($\nu$) which is further contained in A. Here, $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures.

I can see that $\int_{A} f(x) d\mu(x) = \int_{supp(\mu)} f(x) d\mu(x) \geq \int_{supp(\nu)} f(x) d\nu(x) = \int_{A} f(x) d\nu(x)$ because $f$ achieves its maximum on A. Will strict inequality hold whenever $\mu \neq \nu$ and if yes, then why? If not, then why? (remember that even if $\mu \neq \nu$, still they can have equal support).

Moreover, these are general probability measures (which are not convex combination of dirac measures). In case of convex combination of dirac measures, if $A=[0,1], \mu = 1/2 \delta_0 + 1/2 \delta_1 , \nu = 1/3 \delta_0 + 2/3 \delta_1 and f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$, $\mu \neq \nu$  implies equality in the above integrals.

Please take general measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ which are not convex combinations of dirac measures. In that case, please let me know. If $f$ can be modified to get strict inequality in integrals for $\mu \neq \nu$, then please suggest that too.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check the first line, Supp($\mu$) is contained in Supp($\nu$) and both of them are contained in A.

Comment: Let $\alpha := \max_x f(x)$. Theb both of the integrals that you write down are equal to $\alpha \mu(\mathrm{supp}\mu)=\alpha=\alpha \nu(\mathrm{supp}\nu)$, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that is correct because what you are doing is replacing f by its maximum value. That doesn't seem right as f is less than or equal to its maximum value (with respect to x) and not exactly equal to its maximum value. @PhoemueX

Comment: As I understood your question, $f$ attains it's maximum precisely at the points of $A$, meaning that $f \equiv \alpha$ on $A$. If this is not true, you should clarify your question.

Comment: You are evidently right. I should have thought before posting this question. @PhoemueX Can you suggest any such f such that strict inequality holds in above question when $/mu /neq /nu$?